# populate spinner in a fragment using sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, spinner

My objective is to populate a spinner inside of a fragment (TASKS). I have created an sqlite database with a method "public List getChildren()" that returns an ArrayList. Most of the resources and tutorials i have found , help you populate the spinner using an array created in the same class or in an xml file. i cannot find the way to declare an adapter i can use inside of my oncreate method.

SQLDATABASE

```
package com.example.victor.kidsrewards;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Victor on 4/3/2016.
 */
public class ChildDataBase {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private ChildSQLiteHelper childSQLiteHelper;
    String _parentName = Globals._username;

    public ChildDataBase(Context context)
    {
        childSQLiteHelper = new ChildSQLiteHelper(context);
        db = childSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        db.close();
    }
    public void createChild(String childNameText, String nickNameText, String genderText, int ageText )
    {

        String query = "select * from child";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("id", count);
        contentValues.put("childname", childNameText);
        contentValues.put("nickname",nickNameText);
        contentValues.put("age", ageText);
        contentValues.put("gender", genderText);
        contentValues.put("parent", _parentName);

        //insert
        db.insert("child" , null, contentValues);

    }
    public List<ChildUser> getChildren()
    {
        List<ChildUser> childList = new ArrayList<ChildUser>();

        //select columns
        String[] tableColumns = new String[]{"id", "childname", "nickname"};

        Cursor cursor = db.query("child" , tableColumns, "parent =? ",new String[]{_parentName},null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            ChildUser child =new ChildUser();
            //take values from database
            child.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            child.setChildName(cursor.getString(1));
            child.setNickName(cursor.getString(2));


            //add to db
            childList.add(child);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return childList;
    }
}
```

I want to call that public List getChildren() method to help me populate my Spinner here in my onCreateView.

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Tasks extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener {
    private EditText taskText;
    private Button addNew;
    private TaskDataBase tdb;
    private EditText pointsText;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ChildDataBase cdb;
    private ChildSQLiteHelper childSQLiteHelper;



    public Tasks() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);


    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ChildDataBase cdb = new ChildDataBase(getContext());

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, container, false);
        spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.child_spinner);
       setListAdapter(new ChildListAdapter(getContext(), cdb.getChildren()));
        ArrayList<ChildUser> adapter = (ArrayList<ChildUser>) cdb.getChildren();

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, container, false);//fragment_tasks

    return v;


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        taskText = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.newTaskText);
        pointsText = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.newPointsText);

      // spinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.child_spinner);

       //spinner.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) childList);

        addNew = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.addNewTodoButton);

        addNew.setOnClickListener(this);

        tdb = new TaskDataBase(getContext());

        //setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(getContext(), tdb.getTasks()));


    }
   /* @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView 1, View v, int position, long id){

        Task task = (Task)getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        tdb.deleteTask(task.getId());

        setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(getContext(), tdb.getTasks()));

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }*/

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String addNewText = taskText.getText().toString();
        String addPoints = pointsText.getText().toString();
        //if add button was clicked do this
        if(addNew.isPressed() && !addNewText.equals("") && !addPoints.equals("") ){
            String taskTextValue = taskText.getText().toString();
            taskText.setText("");
            String taskpointsValue = pointsText.getText().toString();
            int pointsInt = Integer.parseInt(taskpointsValue);
            pointsText.setText("");
            TaskDataBase tdb = new TaskDataBase(getContext());
            String sampleChild = "sample child"; //place holder c
            //add to db
            tdb.createTask(taskTextValue, pointsInt, sampleChild);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New Task Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tdb.Close();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Task must not be blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my spinner layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.victor.kidsrewards.Tasks">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="TODO TEXT GOES_HERE">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also created a ChildListAdapter class

```
package com.example.victor.kidsrewards;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Victor on 4/3/2016.
 */
public class ChildListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChildUser> {

    private final Context context;

    private final List<ChildUser> childList;

    public ChildListAdapter(Context context, List<ChildUser> childList){
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_child_list_layout, childList);//fragment_child_list
        this.context = context;
        this.childList= childList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_list_layout,parent,false);


        Button childName = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.childButton);
        childName.setText(childList.get(position).getNickName());

      /* TextView taskText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
        taskText.setText(taskList.get(position).getText());

        TextView pointsText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.pointsTextView);
        pointsText.setText(Integer.toString(taskList.get(position).getPoints())+ " Points");*/



        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This is the error i receive

```
Error:(69, 16) error: no suitable method found for setAdapter(ArrayList<ChildUser>)
method Spinner.setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter) is not applicable
(actual argument ArrayList<ChildUser> cannot be converted to SpinnerAdapter by method invocation conversion)
method AbsSpinner.setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter) is not applicable
(actual argument ArrayList<ChildUser> cannot be converted to SpinnerAdapter by method invocation conversion)
method AdapterView.setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter) is not applicable
(actual argument ArrayList<ChildUser> cannot be converted to SpinnerAdapter by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: so whats your problem?

Comment: I apologize, im very new to this. most of the resources and tutorials i have found , help you populate the spinner using an array created in the same class or in an xml file. i cannot find the way to declare an adapter i can use inside of my oncreate method.

Comment: do you getting values in arraylist

Comment: im not sure id i need to implement my ChildListAdapter to achieve this.

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84 go through it

Comment: thank you i will review this resource.